# 1998 Ford Ranger surges when idling

Tags: ford, rough-idle

What should I be looking at to diagnose my Ford Ranger which surges when stopped? This typically only happens while the vehicle is warming up.  After that, it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought is to clean the throttle body and Idle Air Control (IAC) motor passages with carburetor or throttle body cleaner. They get a black buildup on the edge of the throttle plate and IAC passages that interferes with the idle speed regulation.

Answer (score 4):

As Larry said, check the throttle body and the IAC, but I'd also check for vacuum leaks.